# Forwarding Props to React Component flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

The basic idea of forwarding props is that I want to enhance an element,
by composing it. E.g.

```
class MyButton extends Component {
    render() {
        const { busy, children, ...props } = this.props
        return <button { ...props }>
            { busy ? "busy" : children }
        </button>
    }
}
```

Here I can add an extra property (busy) to the button element,
but still have all the properties of the button element passed to the
"real" button.
This saves me a lot of writing, since I don't have to write every
property again. Also if the button interface gets changed my button wrapper
will adapt automatically.

Now I want to do the same thing with flow type annotations.

```
class Button extends Component<props_t, state_t> {
    render() { ... }
}
```

But how should I define the props_t.
If I write

```
type props_t = { busy: boolean }
```

this would only accept a busy property.

My idea was to use a union type and do something like this:

```
import type { ElementProps } from "react"

const button = props => <button { ...props } />
type props_t = {
    busy: boolean
} | ElementProps<(typeof button)>
```

Actually this seams to work, but looks more like a hack because the
props must first be inferred.

Does anybody know a better approach, or how it is typically done?

EDIT:

After some tests I came to the conclusion that the solution above does not work.